# Fullcalendar on IPhone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to use fullcalendar on iphone native app reading events from servlet on a remote server? Features required are Month, Week and Day view. No need of adding, editing or deleting events. Clicking on event display the summary of the event. I would be very happy if fullcalendar is capable of the same, if no what are the other solutions. Expecting your guidance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you certainly can. I just did.

What I discovered though was that with the monthview it quickly gets very cluttered. With the weekView it's not possible because FullCalendar only shows a limited span of hours and you can't scroll up or down.

My particular app uses an API and does not rely on cookies.

You can test it yourself by using your iPhone and going to http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar/demos/json.html